# Any example of a dye molecule (e.g. indigo) where its color could be directly explained from its quantum level spacings?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, visible-light

The color of many insulators can be explained from the spacing between their quantum energy levels. Usual example is chromium level in ruby which absorbs mostly green and yellow but not red, so that ruby is red[1](https://www.forbes.com/sites/chadorzel/2019/07/01/the-mostly-quantum-physics-of-making-colors/#182b80783953).

I'm looking for a similar simple example but for a chemical dye present in our daily life (for example indigotin molecule in jeans). So that I could illustrate how quantum physics helps understand some of the colors around us, for example the color of our clothes. Any idea where I could find such data similar to that of ruby ?
Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "color"? Do you mean the full spectrum? If so, what spectral resolution is acceptable?

Comment: I'm not into refined details. For example Ruby looks red because most of the spectrum absorption lies into green and yellow. If the spectrum of a blue dye like indigo was showing that most absorption lies in green-yellow-red region of the spectrum, that's enough for me to say why it's blue.